# Returning a Modal with relationships after creating in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a modal for example User. The User has relationships to Country and Currency modal as well. I would like to return a JSON object of the User with their relationships. I can achieve that using the code below:

```
    $user = User::create($request->all()); // request contains all the information to create the user

    $userDetails = User::with('country', 'currency')->where('id', $user->id)->first();

   return json_encode($userDetails);
```

It works. However, is there a better or more recommended way to achieve this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that creating a new Laravel Resource and using the following approach seems much cleaner:

```
// in UserResource.php:
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'country' => $this->country, // relationship
        'currency' => $this->currency // relationship
    ]
}

// In controller:
return new UserResource($user);
```

Thanks!